# How to Set Default Value In Material Ui Multiple Select in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I want to set some values in multiple select but how to do it can anybody please help me ?
and ***valueSheet.userFullName*** is the array of all users and I want set some values to dropdown. Thanks In Advance :))

```
export default function MultipleSelectBox() {
  const valueSheet = useContext(ContextSheet);

  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event, key) => {
    const itemKey = key.key.slice(2);
    console.log("keyyy", itemKey);
    valueSheet.setUserUid(current => [...current, itemKey]);
    const { target: { value } } = event;
    setPersonName(
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
    );
    console.log("getSelectedValue", event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-standard-label">Users List :</InputLabel>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 210 }} size="small">
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-checkbox-label">Users</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Users" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            console.log("selectedd", selected);
            return selected.map((s) => s.FullName).join(", ");
          }}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >

          {valueSheet.userFullName.map((name) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={name.id} value={name}>
                <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
                <ListItemText primary={name.FullName} />
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've little bit refactored your code example by adding new property `isChecked` and introduced template for `renderValue`:

```
renderValue={(selected) => {
        console.log("selectedd", selected);
        return selected.map((s, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <MenuItem key={"menuItem" + index} value={s.FullName}>
              <Checkbox key={"checkbox" + index} checked={s.isChecked} />
              <ListItemText
                key={"listItemText" + index}
                primary={s.FullName}
              />
            </MenuItem>
          </div>
        ));
      }}
```

So it is possible to set selected value by using `useState`:

```
const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([
    { id: 2, FullName: "john", isChecked: true },
    { id: 4, FullName: "havvana", isChecked: true }
]);
```

### UPDATE:

Your logic of selecting values should be edited. I mean you should use
`setPersonName` to select or deselect values in `select` control. The code would look like this:

```
const handleChange = (event, key) => {    
    const fullName = event.target.value.slice(-1).pop()
    console.log("fullName", fullName)

    const selectedPerson = usersList.find(u => u.FullName === fullName)
    console.log("selectedPerson", selectedPerson)
    if (selectedPerson && !personName.some(person=> person.FullName === fullName))
    {
       setPersonName(prevArray => [...prevArray, selectedPerson]) 
    } else {
      const updatedArray = personName.filter( p=> p.FullName !== fullName)
      setPersonName(prevArray => [...updatedArray]) 
    }

    console.log("event.target.value", event.target.value);
    console.log("personName", personName)
};
```

[A complete codesandbox example can be seen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-chebyshev-nszxyd?file=/src/Select.jsx).

Comment: Yes I know But how to use In my Scenario ? because my data is not static.

Comment: @HumailSaleem could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vkhep6?file=src%2FApp.js) example?

Comment: Here It is [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-rgb-3ri4n5?file=/src/Select.jsx)

Comment: @HumailSaleem Feel free to ask any question. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Comment: your answer is not valid because the item is selected but I cannot checked the selected value and also default selected value not remove its fixed :(

Comment: Its Right , But one problem is occur dude the value is duplicated, once you set the value then again select the item, the item is again selected, check your answer again i guess somthing wrong :((